# What is the resolution of the Apple Thunderbolt Display's built-in camera?

Tags: webcam

Apple's tech specs for the Thunderbolt Display merely lists a:

> Built-in FaceTime HD camera with microphone

I've not been able to find what the maximum possible resolution is. I say maximum possible because Photo Booth takes 4:3 pictures, where Quicktime Player's video recording can take what I believe is a full frame, 16:10 (or 16:9) video.

What is the maximum possible resolution image and/or video that a Thunderbolt Display's built-in webcam can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4:3 or 16:10 or 16:9 is aspect ratio.  As for maximum resolution, open Quicktime to do a video recording thru the camera and set the quality to maximum.  You don't have to hit record, just do ⌘+i for the movie inspector and you will see the recording resolution there.  The camera will record at the highest possible resolution it can.

Comment: And the answer is 1280x720, or more succinctly, 720p. I probably should have figured that.